# New file in folder gets automatically added to TFS (TFVC) pending changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

Team Foundation Server 2018 / Visual Studio Professional 2017 - Version 15.9.5

When i manually create a new file in Windows Explorer in a certain directory that is part of the TFVC source controlled tree, that file gets automatically added to TFVC pending changes (as "add"). Note that the file is not part of any project.
(The solution was opened in Visual Studio at the time the file was created).

This does not happen in other directories. I can add files to windows directories and they will NOT automatically be added to TFS and need to be manually added to TFS within VS Source Explorer. This is the expected behavior for me.

So it seems it is some configuration of a specific folder?, but i can't find it.
Didn't even know this was possible.
Can you tell me where to look?

FYI, this is a local workspace.

Edit: I have the TFS Explorer extension installed.

Edit: The new file is only added to pending changes when VS is open when creating the file in the folder. I did a test with VS closed, then create new file. Then reopen VS with solution and the file does NOT appear as a pending add.

Comment: You used to have to go through a Team Foundation context menu in windows explorer a few versions back. Then they said that TFS would check out automatically just by editing. I have seen this (inconsistently) myself and though that it was related to being a local (as opposed to a server) workspace. The docs say regarding local, "It may be also be preferable to you if you do not need to work as part of a team and strongly prefer working with the file system in a manner similar to Git.". To me that sounds like what you are describing. Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce today when I tried.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this issue every time you create a new file in the certain directory? If you add files outside VS, it's supposed to detect the files in `Excluded Changes`.

Comment: @MikeCheel:
I understand that TFS checks out automatically when editing (files under version control that is). But here the file is new and it isn't part of version control. The problem is that it is magically added to version control just by creating it in the folder. Also note that this happens only for files created in a particular part of the folder tree.

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT:
Yes, i do reproduce this for any new file under ceratin folders. (but not other folders)
My previous experience with the other folders is that VS does NOT detect adding files to folders outside of VS - unless i add them manually in Source Control.

Comment: @Scrontch Could you try to re-map the directories to a new folder to see whether you have this issue?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT Didn't try, but it happens many in my team have the same issue with the same folders, so i can exclude my particular personal mappings as error sources i guess.

Comment: Edited: In case it is relevant: I have the TFS Explorer extension installed.

Comment: Have you tried using a .tfignore at the root of the workspace see:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops#tfignore-file-rules you can ignore all sort of file and folder with this.  It's the same concept as a gitignore file but for TFVC

Comment: @Etienne: That's a workaround, but i still want to understand the strange behavior.

Comment: @Scrontch It seems when you add files, it's detected as VS added, not Windows added, is it possible to provide a way to reproduce this issue?

Comment: @CeceDong-MSFT: I can't share the project for confidentiality reasons. But i could share particular files or entries. Which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

When your workspace is configured as a `Local workspace`, files and folders are automatically detected and added (unless excluded by a `.tfignore` file).

[Generally Local Workspaces are way more convenient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511), and are the default for workspaces with fewer than 100000 files (and with a fast system can exceed that number). [It can be beneficial to configure a good tfIgnore file to control what is added automatically and what is ignored](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/add-files-server?view=azure-devops&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5001511#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control).

When there are no explicitly Included changes in your Team Explorer and you're in a local workspace, Visual Studio(2017+ from the to of my head) assumes you want to add all new changes and will auto-include them.

When your workspace is configured as a `Server workspace`, files and folders need to be manually added/removed, unless the changer are made through an IDE that is aware of the repository (Visual Studio will auto-add changes made in the solution explorer).

You can check the type of your workspace from the commandline:

```
tf workspaces /format:detailed /collection:https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing
```

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise>tf workspaces /format:detailed /collection:https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing
=======================================================================================================================
Workspace  : JACKIE
Owner      : Jesse Houwing
Computer   : JACKIE
Comment    :
Collection : https://dev.azure.com/jessehouwing
Permissions: Private
Location   : Local
File Time  : Current

Working folders:
```

Or from Visual Studio:

[image: See workspace type in Visual Studio]